# Unresolved property variable when returned from method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, intellij-idea, webstorm

...

```
doChunk().then(function (results) {
   angular.forEach(results, function (info) {
      if (info.data.fields.worklog) {
         configProcess.results.push(info.data);
```

...

The above is just a sample from my `AngularJS` application, but it's the same issue for all data (and vanilla JS) that's returned from somewhere else - like an `HTTP` request in this case.

results - is the result of an HTTP request and contains an array of objects.

So when I loop over this array I access different properties of these objects.
All is fine and it works, but how can I declare what the different properties of these methods are?

Basically what I want is to get rid of code inspection errors from *WebStorm* like these: `Unresolved variable fields at line 106`.

It makes perfect sense to me why it's reported, but how do I address it?

Comment: What do you mean by "All is fine and it works, but how can I declare what the different properties of these methods are?"? Expand this and I might be able to help :)

Comment: You can right-click the the area near scrollbar and chose  'Customize hightlighting level' and in that dialog, click 'Configure Inspections'. There you can turn off the 'Unresolved variable' under JS.

Comment: IntelliJ / WebStorm complains about:
"Unresolved variable fields" in the above code. Which makes sense, since how is anyone/anything supposed to know that the object "info" actually contains: "info.data.fields.worklog"?

Do I need to do something like:
info.data = info.data ? info.data : {};
info.data.fields = info.data.fields ? info.data.fields : {};

Must be a better way?

Comment: @marekful - Yes, I could do that. But I don't wish to disable it globally, just in cases like this. Maybe I would be sufficient if I could disable the inspection on a case by case basis - but that doesn't seem possible(?).

Comment: I understand your frustration. it did annoy me a lot and could only come up with these 2 solutions: disable it globally OR define those properties individually but this latter seems unrealistic.